# How to round float value to nearest multiple of 5

Tags: android, math, rounding

I want to conver the float value into int 
I tried Math.round(float value) but this converts to nearest integer but i want to do converts the int value should be division of 5  for example
456 it should convert to 455 or of it 458 it ahould convert to 460.

Answer (score 1):

You could first divide by 5 and then use Math.Ceiling to round the value. Afterwards, u can multiply by 5 again.

```
int rounded = (int) Math.Ceiling(Number / 5) * 5
```

Comment: Doesn't that always round up? (i.e. 456 -> 460)

Comment: Great. Vote for my answer bro

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
5*Math.round(value / 5.0)
```

Answer (score -1):

write code something like this

```
float your_value = value / 10;
int result = 10 * Math.round(your_value);
```